# Execute shell command in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

My question is about What is the difference between **sh 'date'** and **sh ("date")**? This is one of the steps in Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Grammar; layout.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. In some situations, Groovy allows for optional parenthesis. From [the documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses)

> Groovy allows you to omit the parentheses for top-level expressions, like with the `println` command:
>
> ```
> println "Hello"
> method a, b
> ```
>
> vs:
>
> ```
> println("Hello")
> method(a, b)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have a sample declarative Jenkinsfile which displayed the stdout of date command for sh 'date' and did not display anything for sh ("date")

Comment: @YashRao in order to get help it would be best to frame the question as an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).